# Help finding a thixotropic suspension with specific properties for 3d printing

Tags: experimental-chemistry, polymers, reference-request

I currently doing research on 3d printing on circuit boards. The technique we are using is to put a conductive material, I.e ceramics/metal in a gel/polymer, to print the suspension and then when is complete to sinter away the gel/polymer. The problem I am having is the suspension needs to be thixotropic. Furthermore it must have a high viscosity i.e 500 cpa under low shear and to quickly drop to low viscosity as the shear increases

So far the closest thing I have been able to find is in this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0955221909003860) but if you look at the graphs none of them have a high enough viscosity and more importantly the drop to low viscosity under increasing shear is too shallow.

I have tried to use models like the ones in this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377025714001463#s0055) but I am finding it quite difficult.

Does anyone have any suggestions to find more materials like the one I require? Thanks

Comment: "500 cpa" -- what is cpa? I'm aware of $\pu{Pa \cdot s}$ and $\pu{cP}$, but cpa is something new to me.

Comment: my apologies I meant Pa s

Comment: @IntentFilters there's an SE site specifically for 3d printing you know. Do check it out, maybe you will get better answers: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have done so thanks. Unfortunately no answers so here I came.